# Datagram Packet FTP application

Tags: java, ftp

I write a FTP application using UDP Datagram Protocol , and I need the client side read from file 100 character and send it in 5 parts , 20 characters in each part , when I run my program I get this error :
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal length or offset`. I want the server get each line in five parts but sort it accordingly.
this is my code :

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class FTPClient
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         final int SIZE=100;
         DatagramSocket skt= null;
         DatagramPacket pkt = null;
         BufferedReader read= null;
         int port = 3131;
         try
         {
             skt=new DatagramSocket(2121);
             read= new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
             String line = read.readLine();
             byte[] lineByte = new byte[SIZE];
             lineByte = line.getBytes();
             InetAddress add = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");

             for(int i=0;i<100;i+=20)
             {
                  pkt = new DatagramPacket(lineByte,i,20,add,port);
                  skt.send(pkt);
             }

         }

         catch(IOException e)
         {
             System.out.println(e.getMessage()); }

         finally
         {
             skt.close();
          // read.close();
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code with comments at problem areas. If you still have problems resolving the issues after reading my comments, just add a comment and I will explain more

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int SIZE = 100;
    DatagramSocket skt = null;
    DatagramPacket pkt = null;
    BufferedReader read = null;
    int port = 3131;
    try {
        skt = new DatagramSocket(2121);
        read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
        String line = read.readLine(); // how long is the line?
        byte[] lineByte = new byte[SIZE]; // this is a redundant assignment
        lineByte = line.getBytes(); // now the length of the lineBytes is "unknown"
        InetAddress add = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i += 20) { // you should check the length of lineBytes instead of 100
            pkt = new DatagramPacket(lineByte, i, 20, add, port);
            skt.send(pkt);
        }

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally {
        skt.close();
        // read.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's unimportant to check the length for me , I assumed that is 100 characters

Comment: You can't assume that it is 100. The `read.readLine()` only read one line, that is, reads everything upto the first newline character.